# Как вывести все данные из таблицы SQLite в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, sqlite

Имеется код, но он выводит только последнюю строку

```
    public void Show_DB()
    {
        connection();
        try
        {
            cmd_db = new SqliteCommand("SELECT * FROM Items", con_db);
            rdr = cmd_db.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                IDtext.text = rdr[0].ToString();
                Nametext.text = rdr[1].ToString();
                Counttext.text = rdr[2].ToString();
                Desctext.text = rdr[3].ToString();
                Statustext.text = rdr[4].ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            text.text = ex.ToString();
        }
        Disconnect();
    }
```

Как это можно исправить?
Нужно, чтобы код выводил все строки из БД, в UnityUI Text.
К примеру, Нужно чтобы все id вываливались в блок IdText, и каждый начинался с новой строки. 
Лучше бы, конечно, чтобы на каждую строку создавался новый префаб, содержащий эту строку, чтобы можно было сделать динамический список.

Comment: Код поочерёдно выводит новую строку, перезаписывая старую. Напишите в вопросе, какого результата вы хотите добиться?

Comment: Нужно, чтобы код выводил все строки из БД, сохраняя предыдущие.

Comment: опишите всё это в вопросе. На текущий момент не понятно, в какой форме вы хотите результаты вывести, должны ли быть какие-то разделители. Возможно вам достаточно заменить `=` на `+=`, а возможно, нужно нечто другое. Дайте сообществу понять, что именно вам нужно.

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае вам достаточно перестать полностью перезаписывать новыми значениями поля `text` в каждой итерации, начав дополнять существующие значения - новыми. Так же необходимо добавлять к строкам `Environment.NewLine` для вставки символа переноса:

```cs
public void Show_DB()
{
    connection();
    try
    {
        cmd_db = new SqliteCommand("SELECT * FROM Items", con_db);
        rdr = cmd_db.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            IDtext.text += rdr[0].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            Nametext.text += rdr[1].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            Counttext.text += rdr[2].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            Desctext.text += rdr[3].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            Statustext.text += rdr[4].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        text.text = ex.ToString();
    }
    Disconnect();
}
```